# Function calls are not supported in decorators in routing module

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to enter different component in one URL by configuration:

**routing.module.ts**

```
const routes = [ 
  // ...
  {
    path: 'members',
    component: applicationInjector.get(ConfigurationService).isAuth
      ? MembersAuthComponent
      : MembersNoAhthComponent
  },
];
```

**main.ts**

```
export let applicationInjector: Injector = null;

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(componentRef => {
    applicationInjector = componentRef.injector;
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

It works fine when I run `ng serve`, but has the error during `ng build --prod`:
 **Error during template compile of 'routingModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'applicationInjector' was called.**

Comment:  Hi @seven  if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting,voting .This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this .

Answer (score 2):

this is the best case to use angular router guard

*Memeber Login Guard*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MemeberGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private ConfigService: ConfigurationService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.configServ.isAuth) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/notauthorized-members');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

routes

```
const routes = [ 
  {
    path: 'members', 
    component: MembersAuthComponent,
    canActivate: [MemeberGuard ]
  }, 
{
    path: 'notauthorized-members', 
    component: MembersNoAhthComponent
  }, 
];
```

read this helpful article [Better Redirects in Angular Route Guards](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/)

Comment: Thank you, that's a solution. But I must use the same URL in my case, do you have a better solution?

Comment: you can create a component wrapper for these components ? is this acceptable for you

Comment: Yeah, use `*ngIf ` in the wrapper component may be the most convenient way.

Comment: I have add an example base of member wrapper component , hop this will slove your problem 

Answer (score 0):

you can create an empty component just to disaply the nedded  component base of the login state

*Member Wrapper Component*

```js
export class MemberWrapperComponent {

  constructor(private configServ:ConfigurationService) { }

  get isAuth(){
    return this.configServ.isAuth;
  }

}
```

template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isAuth;else notAuthMember">
  <app-member></app-member>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #notAuthMember>
 <app-unauthorized-member></app-unauthorized-member>
</ng-template>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhioun)